# How did the Bail-In in Cyprus Work?

Tags: macroeconomics, banking

I've seen some articles online about the [Cyprus-style bail-ins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012%E2%80%9313_Cypriot_financial_crisis)

When the bail-in actually happened there, they took money from people's accounts, but from where did they take the money?

For example, if someone had a CD there or a brokerage account with the bank, were those included as targets for bail-ins? Or was it limited to savings and checking accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's deposit accounts, which I think means *both* savings and checking accounts.

No, brokerage accounts are definitely not it, as they do not represent a liability for the bank. The issue is that the 'bail-in" is a reduction in the debt the bank has towards its depositors. When you own 100 of deposits, it's the bank that owes you, but when you owe a brokerage account that owns 100 of stocks, the bank owes you nothing. So, you received a statement from the bank saying you had 200000 euros in your account, then they impose a 40% levy on the uninsured part (100000). So next month you receive a bank statement that says you have now have 160000 in your account...